# Flutter Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

```
Building without sound null safety For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.10/3f4af7aff21c4ec46e3cdd645639d0a63a68d3d0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.61/70dffc5f8ac5ea7c34f30deac5b9d8b1d48af066/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.61.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.61/4702105e97f7396ae41b113fdbdc180ec1eb1e36/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.61.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.61/65abb71d5afb850b68be03987b08e2c864ca3110/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.61.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.50/50ad05ea1c2595fb31b800e76db464d08d599af3/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.4.20/9de2c79e95d4b4699a455e88ba285a95352e0bea/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.20.jar (version 1.4)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.30/d68efdea04955974ac1020f8f66ef8176bfbce1f/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/b529d1738c7e98bbfa36a4134039528f2ce78ebf/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/3d9cd3e1bc7b92e95f43d45be3bfbcf38e36ab87/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.10/c49d0703d16c6cb1526cc07b9b46486da1dd8a60/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.10/da6a904b132f0402fa4d79169a3c1770598d4702/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.10/6b84d926e28493be69daf673e40076f89492ef7/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.20/9be77b243a362b745e365f286627b8724337009c/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.20.jar (version 1.4)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/525f5a7fa6d7790a571c07dd24214ed2dda352fe/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.30/649ffab7767038323fec0cc41e2d7b0a8f65a378/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/aydemir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.20/c6761d7805b5312302f2bbd78cda68c976ce0c70/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.20.jar (version 1.4) w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           19,4s ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (62.9MB).
```

the app-release.apk size was 33 mb but after updating flutter and Android Studio some warnings showed up and I fixed all of them. This is the last warning how can I fix that.

Im using m1 macbook pro, macOS big sur 11.5.2

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the exact samt problem.

Comment: unfortunately :(

Comment: @Ahmed Aydemir I solved it by updating everything. I installed the latest Android Studio and updated everything that can be updated ;) Then the problem disappeared. It might help you as well.

Answer (score 3):

**My solution for this error**

in *app/build.gradle* : chnage **jdk7** to **jdk8** and chnage **$kotlin_version** to the last stable version like in config below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21"
}
```

also in the base ***build.gradle***

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

After compile the result :

```
 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           11,0s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (23.8MB).
Process finished with exit code 0
```