# Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath: Flutter build warning

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Once I executed `Flutter clean` and `Flutter build apk`, I am getting a big warning. But apk file generates successfully. I also have upgraded the `gradle` plugin for the latest one.
If I need to upgrade some plugins, please specify how to upgrade the plugin at once for every single project, instead of upgrading the plugin one by one for every project.
[image: terminal output]

```
Building with sound null safety 

Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/itzme/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
No issues found.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           87.6s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (23.5MB).
```

Comment: check this answer, i think is the same problem like you [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74499810/5233189)